# Get highest memory usage in a script

Tags: php, memory

Is there a way I can know at what point the script has used the most memory and how much it was?

I know `memory_get_usage()`, but that will return the current memory usage, right?

So if you call it like when the script ends you get the lowest memory count because PHP has freed the memory for most of the stuff.

Comment: Try storing it after every line you want information on, if it was more memory usage than the previous greatest memory usage.

Comment: i prefer to use the os  to determine memory usage, ps in linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

would `memory_get_peak_usage()` work for you? (Introduce in 5.2.0, enable by default in 5.2.1)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php

Comment: I dont think that works, I get a rly low number, a little more than memory_get_usage. And that's not possible because I'm creating like 10 db tables at some point

Comment: I think it is, just b/c it's lower then what you would think doesn't mean it's not working. Creating tables happens in MySQL not php. Here's another article from IBM about it http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-php-v521/